# Erro ao utilizar método Delete no Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, bootstrap-4

Eu tenho uma aplicação em `Angular4` + `Spring boot` com o seguinte erro quando tento executar o método `delete`

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked

A mesma regra de origem me impede de ler o seguinte link http://localhost:8080/api/user3.

(Motivo: cabeçalho CORS ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ está faltando).

Comment: Olá, este é o site do Stackoverflow em português, traduza sua pergunta ou faça ela diretamente no site do Stackoverflow em inglês

Answer (score 0):

No seu código `Spring boot`, você deve cria uma classe que estende a classe `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` e implementar o método `configure(HttpSecurity http)`, fazendo a chamada da função

```
http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
```

Seu código então deve ficar da seguinte maneira:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
    }
}
```